# What is the best way to run a scheduled job

Tags: cron, jobs

I have a project that contains two parts: the first one is a Flask Api and the second one is a script that should be scheduled.
The Flask app is served through a docker image that runs in Openshift.

My problem is where should i schedule the second script. I have access to Gitlab CI/CD but that's not really its purpose.
Building a docker image and running it on Openshift is also not possible because it will run more times than needed if the pods are more than 1.
The only option I'm thinking of is just using a regular server with cron.

Do you have maybe a better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several aspects to your question and several ways to do it, I'll give you some brief info on where to start.

### Pythonic-way

You can deploy a celery worker, that will handle the scheduled jobs. You can look into celery documentation on how to work it out in python: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html

You can probably get a grasp on how to extend your deployment to support celery from [this article on dev.to](https://dev.to/briancaffey/setting-up-a-django-project-in-kubernetes-with-minikube-3k8i), which shows a full deployment of celery:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: celery-worker
  labels:
    deployment: celery-worker
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod: celery-worker
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod: celery-worker
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: celery-worker
          image: backend:11
          command: ["celery", "worker", "--app=backend.celery_app:app", "--loglevel=info"]
          env:
            - name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
              value: 'backend.settings.minikube'

            - name: SECRET_KEY
              value: "my-secret-key"

            - name: POSTGRES_NAME
              value: postgres

            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: user

            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: postgres-credentials
                  key: password
```

### Kubernetes-way

In Kubernetes (Openshift is a distribution of Kubernetes) - you can create a cronjob, which will execute a specific task on a schedule, similar to this:

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 hello --schedule="*/1 * * * *" --restart=OnFailure --image=busybox -- /bin/sh -c "date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster"
```

which I pulled from [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/).

### Cloud way

You can also use a serverless platform, e.g. AWS Lambda to execute a scheduled job. The cool thing about AWS Lambda is that their free tier will be more than enough for your use case.

See AWS [example code here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/python/example_code/lambda/scheduled_lambda)